# Xamarin Android aapt.exe crash

Tags: android, xamarin

Here is the crash log

```
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FloatingActionButton-Xamarin\library_project_imports\res (TaskId:137)
1>    AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths:  (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\34825E7FFE08E8C31729F34441C18806 (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\27E771DD6EF951D44A389A46F4EB9118 (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\F0A42F786FACB19336B8949BF519880A (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\E434406736FD5B96F6CBCC8C9BCB82D1 (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\AB340F414EC4ECB8B7148A4D95FFEBD6 (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\3C1A96CD36ECB4DF830C1E46707E1D1B (TaskId:137)
1>      D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\59CA20523B7872BFFDCB81BFCECFBE2A (TaskId:137)
1>    LibraryProjectJars:  (TaskId:137)
1>      obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FloatingActionButton-Xamarin\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar (TaskId:137)
1>      obj\Debug\__library_projects__\UniversalImageLoader\library_project_imports\UniversalImageLoader.jar (TaskId:137)
1>    ExtraArgs: --no-version-vectors (TaskId:137)
1>    CreatePackagePerAbi: False (TaskId:137)
1>    ResourceNameCaseMap: values\Strings.xml|values\strings.xml;layout\Intro.axml|layout\intro.xml;layout\SignUp.axml|layout\signup.xml;drawable\signup_editText.xml|drawable\signup_edittext.xml;layout\Login.axml|layout\login.xml;layout\fragment_Pager.axml|layout\fragment_pager.xml;layout\fragment_GroupDialog.axml|layout\fragment_groupdialog.xml;layout\template_fragment_groupDialog.axml|layout\template_fragment_groupdialog.xml;layout\toolbar.axml|layout\toolbar.xml;layout\Main.axml|layout\main.xml;layout\fragment_Discover.axml|layout\fragment_discover.xml;layout\template_fragment_Discover.axml|layout\template_fragment_discover.xml;drawable\UI_Buttons.xml|drawable\ui_buttons.xml;layout\Settings.axml|layout\settings.xml;layout\template_Settings_RecyclerView.axml|layout\template_settings_recyclerview.xml;layout\fragment_CreatePost.axml|layout\fragment_createpost.xml;drawable\createPost_editText.xml|drawable\createpost_edittext.xml;layout\ImagePreview.axml|layout\imagepreview.xml;drawable\intro_MainImage.png|drawable\intro_mainimage.png;layout\Me.axml|layout\me.xml;layout\fragment_Feed.axml|layout\fragment_feed.xml;layout\fragment_Notifications.axml|layout\fragment_notifications.xml;layout\FollowingFollowers.axml|layout\followingfollowers.xml;layout\template_FollowingFollowers_RecyclerView.axml|layout\template_followingfollowers_recyclerview.xml;drawable\followingFollowers_Buttons.xml|drawable\followingfollowers_buttons.xml;layout\UserAccountInfo.axml|layout\useraccountinfo.xml;drawable\UserAccountInfo_followingFollowers_Buttons.xml|drawable\useraccountinfo_followingfollowers_buttons.xml;layout\Search.axml|layout\search.xml;menu\menu_searchView.xml|menu\menu_searchview.xml; (TaskId:137)
1>  D:\Tools\SDK\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package -f -m -M C:\Users\niazi\AppData\Local\Temp\e4o5atr4.bwb\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml -J C:\Users\niazi\AppData\Local\Temp\e4o5atr4.bwb --custom-package com.slash.slash -F C:\Users\niazi\AppData\Local\Temp\e4o5atr4.bwb\resources.apk.bk -S obj\Debug\res -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FloatingActionButton-Xamarin\library_project_imports\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\34825E7FFE08E8C31729F34441C18806\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\27E771DD6EF951D44A389A46F4EB9118\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\F0A42F786FACB19336B8949BF519880A\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\E434406736FD5B96F6CBCC8C9BCB82D1\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\AB340F414EC4ECB8B7148A4D95FFEBD6\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\3C1A96CD36ECB4DF830C1E46707E1D1B\res" -S "D:\OnGoing Projects\Slash\Android\slashandroid\Slash\obj\Debug\resourcecache\59CA20523B7872BFFDCB81BFCECFBE2A\res" -j obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FloatingActionButton-Xamarin\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar -j obj\Debug\__library_projects__\UniversalImageLoader\library_project_imports\UniversalImageLoader.jar -I D:\Tools\SDK\platforms\android-24\android.jar --extra-packages com.github.clans.fab --auto-add-overlay --no-version-vectors  (TaskId:137)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1271,2): error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
1>Done executing task "Aapt". (TaskId:137)
```

Comment: Check whether any of your resources have invalid naming all resources should have smaller case names should not start with a number or special charecter

Comment: i checked for that now i am deleting local/appData to check it

Answer (score 0):

Probably You updated the sdk and from here these problems.

1. Clean bin/debug and bin/release folders in your project
2. Go to local/appData find your Xamarin folder and also clean it.
3. Clean project, rebuild and try compile.